# Stay on same page when error occur in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new in Node.js. Please give me some solutions regarding this.

I am just created the registration form and posting the page, And I have used Mongoose validation. How to stay on the same page from where I am posting the request, because its showing the posted page with error message.

```
 router.post("/formpost", upload.array('myFile', 12), function(req, res, next){
    var user1 = new User({
      firstname:req.body.first_name,
      lastname: req.body.last_name,
      email: req.body.email,
    });
    user1.save(function(err){
     if (err) {
        res.send(errMessage);  
     }
     else
     {
       res.send("Success");
     }
  });
});
```

Or if I am using,

```
return next(new Error(errMessage));
```

then its showing the complete error message on the page. but still its on the posted page

Answer (score 2):

Use `res.redirect('back');` whenever you find some error!

Comment: Its redirect to back but its reset/clear all the form fields. I need to persist the form values also.

Comment: If you dont want to clear the fields then you should use ajax instead of direct get/post request!

Comment: Ok Thanks for your suggestions !